# Как создать анимацию css правилу с jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть код, который отвечает за переключение слайдера. Нужно создать плавную анимацию, каким образом это можно сделать?
Вот код:

```
 $(e.target).parent().parent().find('.content-slider').css({
            'transition': '.3s ease-out',
            'left': function (index, value) {
                if (parseFloat(value) === -540) {
                    return value = 0;
                }
                return parseFloat(value) - 270 + 'px';
            }
        });
```

Comment: animate() возможно вам поможет http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2):

Пропиши transition в css

```js
$(document).hover(function () {
  $('#anim').css('left', '220px');
}, function () {
  $('#anim').css('left', 0);
});
```

```css
#anim {
  transition: left .3s ease-out;
  
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="anim"></div>
```

Comment: Крайне не рекомендуется анимировать что-либо, кроме `opacity` и `transform`.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko почему?

Comment: В целом, потому что это плохо сказывается на производительности, а конкретно в данном случае потому, что при анимации свойства `left`, в отличие от `transform: translate`, не будет субпиксельного рендеринга. Вот есть хорошая статья с объяснением: https://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Comment: На производительности это не сказывается никак, зачастую больше трансформация кушает. В любом случае, есть замечательное свойство `will-change` (https://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change-1/#propdef-will-change), которое включает аппаратное ускорение для рендера. То, что субпиксельный рендеринг будет отсутствовать в left, это да, тут вопрос визуальщины. Но автор конкретно спрашивал про left, значит его скрипт был завязан на свойстве left. 

В вашем комментарии ответа на вопрос «почему не рекомендуется анимировать что-либо, кроме opacity и transform» я не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(e.target).parent().parent().find('.content-slider').html(function() {
  var l;
  if(parseFloat($(this).attr('value')) === -540){
    l = 0;
  }else{
    l = parseFloat($(this).attr('value')) - 270;
  };
  $(this).animate({left: l + 'px'}, 300)
});
```